# android scroll view on whole activity having listview

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, button, scrollview

I want a specific requirement for a android activity . Creating a forum activity with title, post, comments as list and a comment button .

The Requirements are :

1. Title on top
2. post below that
3. username who posted this post
4. comments as List view
5. comment button always shown at the bottom of the activity layout .
6. Everything defined above as a scroll view

The problem i am facing here is when height of title and post increases the listview and button goes out of the android view .When i tried to put scroll view on whole activity button appears just below the listview not always on bottom.

P.S I am beginner to android.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.trippals.android.SinglePostView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/clubtitle"
android:background="@drawable/abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_ligh    t"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
  />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/data"
    android:layout_below="@+id/clubtitle"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/abc_list_selector_background_transition_holo_light"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/user"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_below="@+id/data"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/user"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:weightSum="2"
    >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/commentList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.8"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:dividerHeight="10.0sp"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".2"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1"
    >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/commentbox"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="comment"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_weight=".9"
    />
 <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_play_dark"
        android:id="@+id/addbutton"
     android:layout_weight=".1"
 />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pbLoadingpost"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
```

Comment: instead of listview opt for linear layout as listview doesn't work properly unless it is match parent height and width

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have a look at this page: 
http://blog.lovelyhq.com/setting-listview-height-depending-on-the-items/

As Ashim said, if you want to use ListView in ScrollView you have to set the height of the ListView depending on the number of items (you should not have a ListView that scrolls through items when it is child of a ScrollView which should handle the scrolling).

Answer (score 0):

To use listview inside a scrollview, you need to give fixed height to the listview programmatically at run time i.e item count * item height, 
becouse ScrollView need to know the height of every view inside it.

use this code to get height of a listview.

```
int totalHeight = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
    View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
    listItem.measure(0, 0);
    totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same problem. But when I took udacity android design tutorial then I learned how to identify which layouts to be used according your requirement. There is a single video which teach how to identify layout . I promise it will help you lot.
My solution to your problem is :
You keep your buttons which you want to show always at the bottom of the activity out of Scroll view and keep the height of the scroll view to match parent with margin required for your buttons height.